# Comparing two json files ID values as comparing factor and displaying the corresponding match using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, json, html, compare

The following are json files

1.question.json

```
[{
"Question":"Name any 5 flowers",
"id":["158_-121634659","158_-195702286","158_86710893","158_18978332","158_-58432062"]
}]
```

2.answer.json

```
[{
    "Group": "Beautiful",
    "id": "158_-121634659",
    "SubField": "Cloud Pricing and ROI Calculators",
    "Module": "Flowers",
}, {
    "Group": "colourful",
    "Field": "Related Links",
    "id": "158_-195702286",
    "SubField": "Guidance Toold to Determine which Subscription to include in Solution",
    "Module": "Flowers",
}, {
    "Group": "attractive",
    "Field": "Related Links",
    "id": "158_86710893",
    "SubField": "Customizations & Integrations",
    "Module": "Flowers",
}, {
    "Group": "Sweetsmelling",
    "Field": "Related Links",
    "id": "158_18978332",
    "SubField": "Market Price Guidance",
    "Module": "Flowers",
}, {
    "Group": "Large",
    "Field": "Cost Guidance",
    "id": "158_-58432062",
    "SubField": "",
    "Module": "Flowers",

}]
```

I need to compare each element of ID array with the each json object(id)in another file and display corresponding content related to ID(if matches).

```
   function jsonLoadFile() {
    var input, file, fr;
    if (typeof window.FileReader !== 'function') {
        alert("The file API is not supported in this browser");
        return;
    }
    input = document.getElementById('fileinput');
    if (!input) {
        alert("couldn't find the fileinput element");
    }
    else if (!input.files) {
        alert("This browser doesn't seem to support the `files` property of file inputs.");
    }
    else if (!input.files[0]) {
        alert("Please select a file before clicking 'Load'");
    }
    else {
        file = input.files[0];
        fr = new FileReader();
        fr.onload = receivedText;
        fr.readAsText(file);
    }

   function receivedText(e) {
          lines = e.target.result;
          var newArr = JSON.parse(lines);
          for(i=0; i<newArr.length;i++){
          var span = document.createElement("span");
          var data= "<b>"+newArr[i].Question+"</b>";
          document.getElementById('myContent').innerHTML= myContent.innerHTML+ data;
                  }

}
}
 function jsonLoad() {
    var output,files, f;
    if (typeof window.FileReader !== 'function') {
        alert("The file API is not supported in this browser");
        return;
    }
    output = document.getElementById('fileoutput');
    if (!output) {
        alert("couldn't find the fileinput element");
    }
    else if (!output.files) {
        alert("This browser doesn't seem to support the `files` property of file inputs.");
    }
    else if (!output.files[0]) {
        alert("Please select a file before clicking 'Load'");
    }
    else {
        files = output.files[0];
        f = new FileReader();
        f.onload = receivetext;
        f.readAsText(files);
    }

   function receivetext(e){
   content=e.target.result;
   var Arr=JSON.parse(content);
   for(j=0;j<Arr.length;j++){
   var s=document.createElement("s");
   s.setAttribute("class", "");
   var sp=s.outerHTML;
   if(Arr[j].SubField != ""){
                    var d= sp+' '+"<b>"+Arr[j].SubField+"("+
                    Arr[j].Group+")"+"</b>"+"<br>"+"<br>"+' '+"ID : "+Arr[j].id+"<br>"+
                    Arr[j].Content+"<br>";
            }
            else {
                    var d= sp+' '+"<b>"+Arr[j].Field+"("+
                    Arr[j].Group+")"+"</b>"+"<br>"+"<br>"+' '+"ID : "+Arr[j].id+"<br>"+
                    Arr[j].Content+"<br>";
            }

            document.getElementById('Contents').innerHTML= Contents.innerHTML+ d;
            }
```

}
    }

In the above code i have used two FileReader() functions for two read two different JSON files to display the content of Json according to the conditions

Where can i implement the comparison code

Comment: I don't see any code comparing the id's...is that your question, how to write the code?  You'll likely need 2 nested loops iterating through each ID with every ID in the other file, then move to the 2nd ID in the first file, etc.  Does this help at all?

Comment: How can i write the code when im loading two json files simultaneously,comparing the json objects and to display

Comment: have you tried nested use of file reader? or creating two different filereader objects?

Comment: No haven't,i'll try that

Comment: @shazam I have created two different Filereader objects in the above code .........But the two Json files are stored in a two different   variables.....the content of Json files is displayed as per the structure in the code.......Where can i implement the comparison code(comparing on the basis of ID's)

Comment: I think you'll need to nest them, like the code snippet in the answer posted below.  In the first function you should have access to the IDs of the file that was loaded.  Iterate through each of those IDs, and inside of an iteration call the 2nd function to load the IDs of the 2nd file.   Without carefully studying the output of your code it's hard to recommend the most efficient solution, but you'll  ahve to nest the comparisions, not call one, then call the other. You need access to both sets of arrays at the same time.  Study the code posted in the answer below.

Comment: I'd suggest naming your functions somethign to help keep things straight "loadQuestionJSON"  & "loadAnswerJSON".  that will help keep things straight as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax can be something like this:

```
var question = [{
"Question":"Name any 5 flowers",
"id":["158_-121634659","158_-195702286","158_86710893","158_18978332","158_-58432062"]
}];

var answer = [{
    "Group": "Beautiful",
    "id": "158_-121634659",
    "SubField": "Cloud Pricing and ROI Calculators",
    "Module": "Flowers",
}, {
    "Group": "colourful",
    "Field": "Related Links",
    "id": "158_-195702286",
    "SubField": "Guidance Toold to Determine which Subscription to include in Solution",
    "Module": "Flowers",
}, {
    "Group": "attractive",
    "Field": "Related Links",
    "id": "158_86710893",
    "SubField": "Customizations & Integrations",
    "Module": "Flowers",
}, {
    "Group": "Sweetsmelling",
    "Field": "Related Links",
    "id": "158_18978332",
    "SubField": "Market Price Guidance",
    "Module": "Flowers",
}, {
    "Group": "Large",
    "Field": "Cost Guidance",
    "id": "158_-58432062",
    "SubField": "",
    "Module": "Flowers",

}];

for(i = 0;i < answer.length; i++){
   for(j = 0;j < question.length; j++){
       if(question[j].id.indexOf(answer[i].id) > 0 ){
       console.log("Match");
   }
}
```

`indexOf` will give you the id's exist or not.

The following part does the comparison:

```
for(i = 0;i < answer.length; i++){
   for(j = 0;j < question.length; j++){
       if(question[j].id.indexOf(answer[i].id) > 0 ){
       console.log("Match");
   }
}
```

Comment: Thank you.....it helped..:)@pritam,If i have Many questions having some similar id's related to their answers and answer.json file with many id's and if i have two different json files one for questions and other for answers stored in a local variable [link](https://plnkr.co/edit/tfWu4it7ryUKzbyqmof7?p=preview)......how can i compare Each question id's @ a time with the json file and display as per my html structure

Comment: @HK123 Sorry. I did not get your question. Can you please elaborate?

Comment: As per your code if we have single question we can store in a variable and can work on comparison with the other answer file.......suppose if i have multiple questions of different Id's but Id's matching in the other json file....How the comparison logic works to display answers for multiple questions

Comment: @HK123 Similar way. Look closely I have written the for loop for a questions array.

Comment: i have modified a code creating two FileReader() functions for two different JSON file reading and stored in two different variables and displaying structure of JSON file as in the code......Where can i implement the comparison code now.....Thank you@pritam